# Euler characteristic of a metrized line bundle

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

During my readings on the web, I found the Euler characteristic of a metrized line bundle, let $L$ a line bundle on a variety $X \to \operatorname{spec}(K)$. And let $\varphi$ a metric on $L$.

Someone has a reference to define this object:
$$ \chi (L,\varphi) $$

I can't find anymore where I saw it.
And if this object really exists, what's the link with Euler's characteristic $ \chi (L)$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for example Lang, Introduction to Arakelov Geometry.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1478168)

Comment: Well, it actually gives an answer to the question, as confirmed by the OP.

Comment: I suspect that much of the pushback against your answer is that it is a bare reference, without any further commentary.  In the future, you might consider adding a little bit of extra information, such as a page number, or a more precise statement of how the text addresses the asker's question.